# adding same variables with different values in loop

Tags: c, for-loop

so, basically I need to ask the user how many numbers he wants to add, and then ask him to input the numbers, but I have no idea how to add the numbers without having them stored in the same variable, or how to add the same variable but with different values, this was extremely easy in pascal, but I don't know how to do it in C.

Here is my code so far...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int i, n, age;
     printf("How many numbers do you want to add?\n");
     scanf("%d", &n);
     for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i++) {
        printf("type in the number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &age);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the code, not a link to it. You'll get a much better reception from the community.

Comment: `i = i++` (this is undefined behavior) --> `i++`

Comment: ok, thanks, will do next time

Comment: You forgot `total += age;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the sum of the numbers entered, you can define a variable for the sum and add each number as it entered.

Note that there is a undefined behavior in your code: `i = i++;` you cannot have both a side-effect and modify `i` in the same expression, unless there is a sequence point, something you are unlikely to find in beginner's code. Just `i++` is sufficient to increment `i`.

Here is how to fix and complete the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int i, n, age, total = 0;
     printf("How many numbers do you want to add?\n");
     if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
         for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             printf("type in the number:\n");
             if (scanf("%d", &age) != 1)
                 break;
             total = total + age;
         }
         printf("the sum is %d\n", total);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n ,age,sum = 0;
    printf("How many numbers do you want to enter\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n > 0) {
        printf("Enter the age");
        scanf("%d",&age);
        sum += age;
        n--;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

This is example where one less variable is needed.

Comment: And what exactly did you achieve by saving a variable?

Comment: I like to write the code where solution can be achieved with minimal number of variables, that's the only reason. Why to have N variables if something can be achieved in less than N variables...

Comment: Makes the code more readable and easy to understand with no performance loss?

Comment: I don't think my code is not readable, but would like to thank you for formatting the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
     int i,n ,age,sum=0;
     printf("How many numbers do you want to enter\n");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     for(i = 1;i<=n;i++){
        printf("Enter the age");
        scanf("%d",&age);
        sum+=age;
     }
     printf("%d\n",sum);
     return;
}
```

Comment: `int ...sum;` --> `int ...sum = 0;`, `printf('%d',sum);` --> `printf("%d\n",sum);`,  `return;` --> `return 0;`

Comment: 2 out of 3, keep going, Also add `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: thanks for your help man, it worked

Comment: Syntax wrong, use double quotes instead of single in printf and scanf

Comment: I cannot understand how this was accepted when it doesn't even work...

Answer (score 0):

Use array.

```
int age[100];
```

and in your for loop ,store all the ages in that array.

```
scanf("%d",&age[i]);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, your solution worked as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the best way to what you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("how many numbers do you want to add?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    int age[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("type in a number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &age[i]);
        while (age[i] <= 0)
        {
            printf("Insert a positive number:\n");
            scanf("%d", &age[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i,n,sum=0;
    int *age;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("How many numbers do you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");
    age = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*n);
    if(age == NULL)
        return -1;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
       printf("Enter the age: ");
       scanf("%d",&age[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Age[%d] %d\n",i, age[i]);

    /*Finally free the memory here*/`
    free(age);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int i,num,age;
    clrscr();
    printf("How many number do you have to enter "):
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf("enter the age[%d]",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&age);
    }
    return();
}
```